# Garbage output to NXT screen

Tags: c++, embedded, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I've been attempting to get nxtOSEK up and running, as there are some C++ projects I'd like to work on with my NXT and in searching the web it seemed to be the most recommended system for doing so.

I've been following [this tutorial (I'm on Mac)](http://www.aribeiro.info/content/nxtosek-mac-osx-106-snow-leopard) for updating my brick and getting it set up, and managed to get to the point where I'm compiling sample programs and downloading them to my brick.

However, when I compile and run the helloworld program (which simply outputs 'OSEK HelloWorld' to the brick's screen, I get a screen full of garbage characters and can only get back by resetting power.

---

**Edit**

During the build process, I noticed the following error:

```
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
```

Could that possibly be part of the issue?

For fun, I'll dump the entire build procedure...maybe an eagle-eyed SO'er will notice something I missed.

```
espais@computron~/Desktop/nxtOSEK/samples_c/helloworld$ make all
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/alarm.c to alarm.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/event.c to event.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/interrupt.c to interrupt.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/osctl.c to osctl.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/resource.c to resource.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/task.c to task.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/kernel/task_manage.c to task_manage.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/config/at91sam7s-gnu/cpu_config.c to cpu_config.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/config/at91sam7s-gnu/lego_nxt/sys_config.c to sys_config.o
Generating OSEK kernel config files from ./helloworld.oil
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
Compiling kernel_cfg.c to kernel_cfg.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/syscalls.c to syscalls.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/ecrobot_bluetooth.c to ecrobot_bluetooth.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/ecrobot_base.c to ecrobot_base.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/ecrobot.c to ecrobot.o
Compiling helloworld.c to helloworld.o
Compiling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/syslib/at91sam7s-gnu/lego_nxt/hw_sys_timer.c to hw_sys_timer.oram
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../lejos_nxj/src/nxtvm/platform/nxt/vectors.s to vectors.o
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/config/at91sam7s-gnu/debug.S to debug.o
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/config/at91sam7s-gnu/lego_nxt/sys_support.S to sys_support.o
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/nxt_binary_header.s to nxt_binary_header.o
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/nxt_entry_point.s to nxt_entry_point.o
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../ecrobot/c/ecrobot_init.s to ecrobot_init.o
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/config/at91sam7s-gnu/cpu_support.S to cpu_support.oram
Assembling ../../ecrobot/../toppers_osek/config/at91sam7s-gnu/irq.s to irq.oram
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_udivsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_divsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_umodsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_modsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_dvmd_tls.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_addsubdf3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_muldivdf3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_cmpdf2.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_clzsi2.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-memcpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-memset.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strcmp.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strcpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strlen.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strncpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rom.elf does
Generating binary image file: helloworld_OSEK_rom.bin
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_udivsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_divsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_umodsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_modsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_dvmd_tls.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_addsubdf3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_muldivdf3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_cmpdf2.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_clzsi2.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-memcpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-memset.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strcmp.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strcpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strlen.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strncpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_ram.elf does
Generating binary image file: helloworld_OSEK_ram.bin
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_udivsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_divsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_umodsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_modsi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_dvmd_tls.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_addsubdf3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_muldivdf3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_arm_cmpdf2.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/thumb/libgcc.a(_clzsi2.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-memcpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-memset.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strcmp.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strcpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strlen.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: Warning: /opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.1/../../../../arm-elf/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-strncpy.o) does not support interworking, whereas helloworld_OSEK_rxe.elf does
Generating binary image file: helloworld_OSEK.rxe
```

---

**Edit again**
And some version info for good measure:

```
FW NBC/NXC   1.07
AVR          1.01
BC4          1.01
Build        3012081214
```

**Edit the third**

Also have garbage on the screen and a frozen brick when running a program which should simply spin the motors.

---

**Edit the fourth**

I believe I've figured out the problem, however I'm still not sure how to go about resolving it.  It turns out that my NXT's firmware wasn't updated.  I tried doing so through both Mac and Windows, yet it doesn't seem to "take."  For instance, I get a Download Success message each time, however I never see the nxtOSEK logo when I start up the NXT.  This would explain why I'm seeing garbage on the screen, but now I don't know why its not flashing properly.

I'm first putting it into firmware update mode (tic-tic-tic), and then doing the flash process..but...nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in to your problem, I can't find anything wrong from your build procedure. But then taking a quick look at http://lejos-osek.sourceforge.net/whatislejososek.htm, it seems that MacOSX is not supported by nxtOSEK. That is probably your problem altogether, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Not supported true, but it seems that it has been done before.  Perhaps I will just use a Windows VM to try the build procedure out.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty for being the only one to answer...I won't be able to try out on the VM until next week, but I'll update my question when I find out.